# gcloud auth login failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, gcloud

Suddenly unable to authenticate gcloud. I have updated the latest gcloud version and tried. no luck.

```
gcloud auth login    
                                                                                                                                                           
Your browser has been opened to visit:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8085%2F&scope=openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fappengine.admin+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcompute+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Faccounts.reauth&state=1FSUjbwce8Y8KvMKQk3ApyZctWh6fR&access_type=offline&code_challenge=4ykYQwjJZN0o4k8J2O2WQdq6MN9cXGehjWPRr86aW0A&code_challenge_method=S256

ERROR: gcloud crashed (ConnectionError): HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x1044ca580>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known'))
```

But network connection looks fine.

````
                                                                                                                                                    
Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.
Checking network connection...done.                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Reachability Check passed.
Network diagnostic passed (1/1 checks passed).

Property diagnostic detects issues that may be caused by properties.
Checking hidden properties...done.                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Hidden Property Check passed.
Property diagnostic passed (1/1 checks passed).```
````

Comment: What OS you are running on and what python version do you have?

Comment: Also, try this way `gcloud auth login --use-oauth2client`

Comment: @AtefH.    mac OS 'Big Sur'

Comment: ~/Downloads > nc -v -z -w 1 oauth2.googleapis.com 443                                                                                                                                                                     
nc: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
~/Downloads > nc -v -z -w 1 googleapis.com 443  Connection to googleapis.com port 443 [tcp/https] succeeded!

Comment: gcloud auth login --use-oauth2client                                                                                                                                                                    
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.login) unrecognized arguments: --use-oauth2client

Comment: Looks like there is a global bug/issue! there are multiple reports for this issue on the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20gcloud)

Comment: thanks @AtefH.  its started working.. seems google dns issue.

Answer (score 0):

mac useres can enable Private Relay(Beta) in icloud settings
this worked for me

Comment: it has been resolved.    ```nc -v -z -w 1 oauth2.googleapis.com 443                                                                                                                                                                                 
Connection to oauth2.googleapis.com port 443 [tcp/https] succeeded!```